# Node cluster worker is undefined when ran in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, node-cluster

I have a simple node setup using node cluster that forks worker processes. When I run it directly using `node index.js` everything works just fine. However, when I create a docker container and try to run in from there, I get an error saying `cannot read property of undefined` when reading `cluster.worker.id`

This is my index.js

```
import cluster from "cluster";
import express from "express";
import config from "./config.js";
import monitorRoutes from "./monitor/routes.js";
import spawnQueue from "./queues/index.js";

if (cluster.isPrimary) {

  for (let i = 0; i < config.NUMBER_OF_WORKERS; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

} else {
  
  const app = express();

  app.use("/", monitorRoutes);

  // create a queue
  const queue = spawnQueue(cluster.worker.id); // this is the problem line

  // on post requests add a task to the queue
  app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    queue.add(
      {},
      {
        attempts: config.DEFAULT_ATTEMPTS,
      }
    );
    // send the notification with queue id
    res.json({
      message: `Job added to be processed by worker ${cluster.worker.id}`,
    });
  });


  app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 5000");
  });
}
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.3
    
LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="..."
LABEL maintainer = ["<my-email>"]

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
RUN ls
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

When I create the image with `docker build` and then run it with `docker run` it stops at the `cluster.worker.id` line at says that `cluster.worker` is undefined. However, this all works perfectly fine outside of docker.

Do I have a problem in my Dockerfile or is there some additional setup I need to run when using node cluster?

Comment: can you show your package.json file ? You are using import syntax (esm) with an older version of node (12). Can you check if `cluster` is resolved to an object ? You can try before accessing cluster.worker.id assert `if (cluster.isWorker) {}`

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me fix this actually. Turns out the problem was that I was using cluster.isPrimary check and that only works in node 16 and higher. So the solution was to either use cluster.isMaster or pull a different version of node

Comment: yes, make sure your local node version (in your environment) is the same that you're requiring in your .Dockerfile, so you get the same behaviour in all cases.